# Opening a file from filechooser with a file's programm in Java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I want to open a file from filechooser with a file's extension. For exapmle, if a user select the file `text.doc`, then the word must open this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file)
```

This will open the file with the default program if there is a default program. If IOException occured then there is no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched.